# Excel Dates Formatting issue

Tags: excel, date

In Excel

Whenever I try adding days to a date (for eg: 3/15/18 1:50 PM)
the result gives me date with two spaces in between date and time. Tried formatting cells, trimming cells replacing space using substring, but nothing worked

```
Date            Days   New_date
3/15/18 1:50 PM   0     3/15/18  1:50 PM
```

Comment: Can you share the formula you are using for the New_date column?

Comment: @Zeph, i would imagine it is something as simple as =a2-b2.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. In cell A1, I entered `45906.588`, and then formatted it as a date `3/14/12 1:30 PM` using the *Format Cells* dialog. I then entered `0` in B1, and in C1 used `=A1+B1`. I got what was expected, without the extra space you describe.

Comment: @Jeeped I can't replicate so I wanted to rule out something out of the ordinary

Comment: Probably a system setting for time date format.  Try applying a custom format...such as what Zeph just posted below

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, you did exactly what I am doing. Can you please try copying only the value to a new column and then check for the format in formula bar?

Comment: Also, irrespective of what format I use, the format does not change in the formula bar. Anyone know why?

Comment: The format on a worksheet cell will not affect the format in the formula bar.  The format of a date in the formula bar relates to your Windows Regional Settings

Comment: hmm. i see the extra space there in the formula bar. I don't believe you can change the format that excel uses in the formula bar though

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are using a custom number format. You can control exactly how your date is formatted here, and there could be an extra space between the date and the time.

[image]

Comment: I checked that and there is only one space. Also, even if I change the format the format does not change. Do you have any clue about it? thanks